# How to search Deals with its properties ‘closedate’ that falls between a date range

Tags: hubspot

I’m getting deals from [GET /deals/v1/deal/paged](https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/methods/deals/get-all-deals) and wanted to know how do I get only the list of deals with closed date falls between a date range (e.g. between 01.Jan.2018 to 31.Jan.2018).

On top of that, does the API support fields sorting?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Derek (from Hubspot) answered to this question in their community forum.

Summary:

1. Hubspot deal API does not support filter and sorting.
2. Use contact list to group contacts based on criteria.
3. Then pull associated deals from the list via API.

Here's the link to the forum post - https://integrate.hubspot.com/t/how-to-search-deals-with-its-properties-closedate-that-falls-between-a-date-range/7789